# Git: Master-thesis subprojects as submodules or stand-alone repositories

Tags: python, git, bash, git-submodules, subproject

I just started using git to get my the code I write for my Master-thesis more organized. I have divided the tasks into 4 sub-folders, each one containing data and programs that work with that data. The 4 sub-projects do not necessarily need to be connected, none off the programs contained use functions from the other sub-projects. However the output-files produced by the programs in a certain sub-folder are used by programs of another sub-folder. 
In addition some programs are written in Bash and some in Python.

I use git in combination with bitbucket. I am really new to the whole concept, so I wonder if I should create one "Master-thesis" repository or rather one repository for each of the (until now) 4 sub-projects. Thank you for your help!

Comment: So rather be posted in a Forum or can I ask for some opinions with an explanatory statement? I am looking for experiences since myself I have none with git.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as devnull says, answers would be highly opinion based, but given that I disagree that that's a bad thing, I'll go ahead and answer if I can type before someone closes the question.  :)

I'm always inclined to treat git repositories as separate units of work or projects.  If I'm likely to work on various parts of something as a single project or toward a common goal (e.g., Master's thesis), my tendency would be to treat it as a single repository.

And by the way, since the .git repository will be in the root of that single repository, if you need to spin off a piece of your work later and track it separately, you can always create a new repository if needed at that point.  Meantime it seems "keep it simple" would mean one repo.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a single master repository for this problem. You mentioned that the output files of certain programs are used as input to the others. These programs may not have run-time dependencies on each other, but they do have dependencies. It sounds like they will not work without each other being present to create the data. Especially if file location (e.g. relative path) is important, then a single repository will help you keep them better organized.